# Fireplace Conversion: Gas log to gas glass

Tags: fireplace

I have a pair of old fireplaces, both of which are gas, but designed to burn wood, and I'd like to pour fireglass in there instead.

My general understanding is that I should replace the pipe with a more glass friendly one (H or U), but I'm struggling to find good tutorials on how to do so.

Thought I'd check here to see if folks had any recommendations or pointers on where to start. I could call the local fireplace company, but this seems easy enough that I should be able to handle it myself, just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Here's a picture of the current fireplace:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not necessarily recommending this vendor but they have useful guide material on their site.
https://www.diamondfireglass.com/installation-fireplace-glass.htm

Basically you need to remove your existing gas pipe (which is a gas-starter tube). Use two channel locks or similar to prevent turning the pipe within the wall.

You can then use a flexible hose rated for gas fireplace installation between your supply pipe and your fire piping. I recommend using a little dope like rectorseal on these connections.

Where your supply line exits the wall and enters the fireplace ensure its entirely sealed with an appropriate fireplace caulking or mortar.

Finally, install your glass media and follow any instructions on the mortar to heat the fireplace up.

Comment: Thanks for your input. To clarify, I would need to unscrew where the red highlighted circle is in this image: https://imgur.com/a/y06fQSY

Comment: Yep. That's a threaded connection. You might want to use some penetrating oil, just be sure to clean it all up

Answer (score 1):

Typically the gas tubes used for LIGHTING a fire in wood will have a few large holes to allow a lot of gas through and get hot quickly, but not be concerned with how much gas flows because it is temporary. For making a gas fireplace, you want a nice flame pattern and it is going to be on continuously. So the U or H shape will give you more but smaller holes to make the flame pattern more spread out and even while not consuming excess gas.

Comment: Makes a ton of sense. I was planning on putting in an H shape one, just want to make sure I do it right :)